# If you shoot 64KeV deuterium nuclei at a crystal of uranium tritide, what is the probability of fusion per ion?

Tags: nuclear-physics

This is a potential fusion-fission hybrid subcritical accelerator-driven reactor. How many fusions do you get per 64KeV deuterium ion shot at a crystal of UT<sub>3</sub>?  Can the orientation of the crystal lattice matter at all?

64KeV is the peak for the cross section of D-T fusion, and after 1 scattering off a trition or an electron the deuteron would lose enough kinetic energy to make the probability of subsequent fusion small enough to ignore if we're just going for the 1 significant figure.

Comment: How do you get 64keV as the peak of the cross section?

Comment: source for 64KeV: https://www-naweb.iaea.org/napc/physics/fusion-basic.htm#:~:text=For%20the%20D%2DT%20case%20the,kinetic%20energy%20of%2064%20KeV.

Comment: That is the center-of-mass energy, not your situation.

Comment: I would go with cross sections based on the D ion energy. Then perform a SRIM simulation to get an average ion energy vs areal density. Now you can evaluate, for a given slice in areal density, the probability for the fusion reaction to occur.